# how do i fix a "identifier is undefined" error in a simple C++ application?

Tags: c++, undefined, message, identifier

I have searched everywhere, but to no avail. Could someone tell me what's wrong with this code? It is giving me the "Error: Identifier "XXX" Is Undefined"

```
    #include <windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    if(!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
        return false;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: what is XXX here?

Comment: If my compiler gave me that error, I'd rip it out of my computer and throw it out the window.

Comment: Does it really say "XXX" or is that a placeholder for some symbol that could actually be used to try and resolve the issue?

Comment: XXX is used for TODO comments, possible that you deleted comment marks `//` from a comment. search the XXX line and comment it out

Answer (score 0):

There are no MyRegisterClass nor InitInstance global functions in Windows.h

Comment: I take it the OP made them and hasn't shown them. `MyRegisterClass` backs me up on that.